# Using ffmpeg-sharp, convert a wav to mp3

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, sharpffmpeg

Using the [ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) project, how do I convert a wav to mp3?
I feel silly to ask, but I can't find any explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, for the last comment, I was a little frustrated. Well, I am reading the source from ffmpeg, to find what goes in the original, to be able to know where to start.

Comment: I am a little lost. I gues I don't even know the steps to convert...